# Nullable var inside string template

Tags: nullable, kotlin

Kotlin has a feature called [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates). Is it safe to use nullable variables inside a string?

```
override fun onMessageReceived(messageEvent: MessageEvent?) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onMessageReceived: $messageEvent")
}
```

Will the above code throw `NullPointerException` if `messageEvent` is `null`?

Comment: This could have easily been tested by you in 5 seconds.  Was there some reason you did not just try it, or read the docs?

Comment: @JaysonMinard There is no similar question on StackOverflow, and it is not so easy to find the related topic in docs (as you can see yourself https://www.google.by/search?q=Null+inside+string+template+kotlin). I believe that the only bad question is the one not asked. Now, when it's asked, it can be googled by someone in 5 seconds (without building and running a test app).

Comment: but on stack overflow there is such a thing as a question that shouldn't be asked.  It takes time from people who moderate and review to go through questions that anyone would solve with minimal homework.   So you didn't do any research and post what you tried, a big sign you aren't ready to ask a question.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59995/312466  ... part of a question is "what have you done so far to solve it" of which you didn't try the 3 lines of code.   If you had found some answer you could post it as a self answered question to help others google it later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always make a tiny project on try.kotlinlang.org and see for yourself:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    test(null)
}

fun test(a: String?) {
    print("result: $a")
}
```

This code compiles fine and prints `null`. Why this happens? We can check out the documentation on [extension functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), it says that `toString()` method (which will be called on your `messageEvent` parameter to make `String` out of it) is declared like so:

```
fun Any?.toString(): String {
    if (this == null) return "null"
    // after the null check, 'this' is autocast to a non-null type, so the toString() below
    // resolves to the member function of the Any class
    return toString()
}
```

So, basically, it checks if its argument is `null` first, and, if it isn't, invokes member function of this object.